# Checking for HTTPS Website Response Code

Tags: java, url, https, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-503

to begin with - I am new at this page, just created my account because I couldn't handle the problem I am up to.

I am trying to get a response code from the website - what actually interest me is if the page I am checking exists so I am looking for 404 error. I did it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://bittrex.com/dffdgdfgdfgdfgfdgdf");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);

}
```

The URL does not exists but it keeps giving me 403 (Forbidden Access) or 503 (Service Unavailable) response code yet the site is obviously 404ed. I read somewhere that its because of HTTPS protocole and setRequestProperty to pretend being a browser would help but it didn't.

Is there anyway I could fix this so that the site returns 404 error to me? I appreciate help in advance!

Comment: Try using `HttpsURLConnection`.

Comment: Thanks but that did not change the outcome. :(

Comment: You need to do some configuration.  When I access your site from my mobile Chrome I do indeed get 404.  Google around to see how to configure `HttpsUrlConnection`.  I did not say make a one line change and it would work.

Comment: Help me please :(

Comment: Did you follow the advice of my above comment?  Again, I got 404 from my browser.

Comment: I tried to set it up but the program is giving me 503 error instead of 404.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on website response. Hit your link https://bittrex.com/dffdgdfgdfgdfgfdgdf in any browser, it will give you 404. That is the reason you are getting 404.

Below Code give you 200 response code :

```
URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
```

Comment: I would like my program to return code 404 but its giving me 503 (Service Unavailable) error. I think it may be because of cloudflare protection.